# What tools DevOps uses most often?

Tags: devops

I'm really starting my path in DevOps learning.

Please don't answer `ssh`, `ls`, `cd`, `mkdir` etc :)
would be great to know what you guys using to start learning the most used staff first.

Comment: `kubectl` and `zfs`!

Comment: While this is off-topic, as a general note you really need to focus more on specific areas of learning than specific commands. Do you want to learn about storage networks? Databases? Networking and routing? Cluster management? Virtualization? Intrusion detection? You can't learn these all at once. You can, however, pick one that seems interesting and really dig in deep, see how it feels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devops is very loosely defined paradigm.
Different groups have different expectations and implementations of Devops.

You can approach devops tools in two ways:
Note: There are many tools available in each category

Horizontal stack - CICD Tools - Collaboration between Dev and Ops
Source Code repos (Git Repos), CICD Tools + Build Tools (Jenkins, Maven, GOCD), Testing Frameworks ( Selenium ), Software Repos(Artifactory), Code Quality (Sonar), etc.

Vertical Stack - IAC Tools (Terraform), Configuration Management ( Ansible), Container ( Kubernetes, Docker), OS Administration (Linux), DB Administration (Mysql) , Web Server Administration (Nginx), Application Installers and Package Managers, Cloud Providers ( AWS), etc.

You can look into a bash or python scripting as well apart from system design.

Have a read of The Devops Handbook, The Phoenix Project and Accelerate books to get cultural perspective of Devops.